# AngularJS Display JSON data in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

In my module I have a service that calls `$http` and gets an Array of objects,

```
function MenuSearchService($http){       
        this.getMatchedMenuItems=function(searchItem){
             var foundItems =$http({
                method:'GET',
                url:'https://whateverurl.com/whateverdata'
            });
            return foundItems;
        }; // end function
    }; // end service
```

and I use a controller (as a syntax) to process the data,

```
function MenuController(MenuSearchService){
        this.query;
        this.results;
        this.promise;
        this.searchClicked=false;
        this.clickToSearch = function(searchItem){
            this.searchClicked=true;
            this.query=searchItem;
            this.promise=MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems()
            .then(function(result){
                this.foundItems = result.data;
                console.log(this.foundItems);        
                }); 
        }; // end onclick
    }; // end controller
```

I am able to retrieve the data. Here is the stdout of `foundItems`:

[image]

Each object in the `foundItems` has properties `name` and `description`.But when I want to present it in the view,

```
<section class="container" ng-controller="MenuController as m">
    <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in m.foundItems">               
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</section>
```

the data is not shown. Can anyone tell what goes wrong?

---

**Update**
After taking a look at @charlietfl's comment I updated my code to:

```
function MenuController(MenuSearchService){
        var m=this;
        m.query;
        m.promise;
        m.searchClicked=false;
        m.clickToSearch = function(searchItem){
            m.searchClicked=true;
            m.query=searchItem;
            m.promise=MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems()
                .then(function(result){
                        m.foundItems = result.data;                       
                        console.log(m.foundItems);  

                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error.message());
                });
            }; // end onclick
        }; // end controller
```

The concept is wrongly using `this.` in a function inside a controller.

Comment: `this` inside `then()` is not what you think it is. Store a captured reference of `this` once...then only use that variable from then on See [John Papa Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y032)

Comment: IMO, this shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate for the reason it was. There are really two problems here. The first is what charlietfl referenced. The second is the fact that you are treating 'foundItems' as an array, when it is actually an object (result.data is an object). When you console.log foundItems, you see that it is an object that has an array of menu_items in it. So switch your ng-repeat to "item in m.foundItems.menu_items". Or better yet, set foundItems = result.data.menu_items

Comment: @charlietfl should I delete this question?

Comment: you can...it will likely get system deleted at some time. Did the link help?